# The set of WTF-8 strings that are ill-formed UTF-8 as 16-bit slices

Tags: utf-8, rust

I'm trying to define the set of 16-bit slices (Rust: `&[u16]`) that are valid WTF-8 (when re-encoded), but not valid UTF-8 (when re-encoded), so that I can randomly generate such a slice. This in an effort to generate all the possible `std::ffi::OsString`s on Windows machines that do not parse into a `String`.

The conversion `&[u16] -> OsString` is done via [`std::os::windows::ffi::OsStringExt::from_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.from_wide). This redirects into `libstd/sys_common/wtf8.rs` which defines the operation as:

```
/// Creates a WTF-8 string from a potentially ill-formed UTF-16 slice of 16-bit code units.
///
/// This is lossless: calling `.encode_wide()` on the resulting string
/// will always return the original code units.
pub fn from_wide(v: &[u16]) -> Wtf8Buf {
    let mut string = Wtf8Buf::with_capacity(v.len());
    for item in char::decode_utf16(v.iter().cloned()) {
        match item {
            Ok(ch) => string.push_char(ch),
            Err(surrogate) => {
                let surrogate = surrogate.unpaired_surrogate();
                // Surrogates are known to be in the code point range.
                let code_point = unsafe {
                    CodePoint::from_u32_unchecked(surrogate as u32)
                };
                // Skip the WTF-8 concatenation check,
                // surrogate pairs are already decoded by decode_utf16
                string.push_code_point_unchecked(code_point)
            }
        }
    }
    string
}
```

The conversion `OsString -> Result<String, Wtf8Buf>` is done via `into_string` in the same file:

```
/// Consumes the WTF-8 string and tries to convert it to UTF-8.
///
/// This does not copy the data.
///
/// If the contents are not well-formed UTF-8
/// (that is, if the string contains surrogates),
/// the original WTF-8 string is returned instead.
pub fn into_string(self) -> Result<String, Wtf8Buf> {
    match self.next_surrogate(0) {
        None => Ok(unsafe { String::from_utf8_unchecked(self.bytes) }),
        Some(_) => Err(self),
    }
}
```

With `next_surrogate` defined as:

```
#[inline]
fn next_surrogate(&self, mut pos: usize) -> Option<(usize, u16)> {
    let mut iter = self.bytes[pos..].iter();
    loop {
        let b = *iter.next()?;
        if b < 0x80 {
            pos += 1;
        } else if b < 0xE0 {
            iter.next();
            pos += 2;
        } else if b == 0xED {
            match (iter.next(), iter.next()) {
                (Some(&b2), Some(&b3)) if b2 >= 0xA0 => {
                    return Some((pos, decode_surrogate(b2, b3)))
                }
                _ => pos += 3
            }
        } else if b < 0xF0 {
            iter.next();
            iter.next();
            pos += 3;
        } else {
            iter.next();
            iter.next();
            iter.next();
            pos += 4;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is design an algorithm that generates a `Vec<u16>` such that `OsString::from_wide(vec.as_slice()).into_string().unwrap_err()` never panics and gives back a `OsString`. The set of `OsString`s should of course be maximal and not use a trivial constant.

To do this, and to simplify, we can define two operations:

- `encode_wide : &[u8] -> &[u16]`
- `valid_wtf8_invalid_utf8 : () -> Gen<Vec<u8>>` where `Gen` is some sort of monad for generating typed random data.

By mapping the functor given by `valid_wtf8_invalid_utf8()` with `encode_wide` we can get `Gen<Vec<u16>>`, in turn, from this we may get `Gen<OsString>`.

However - I'm not sure how to define the operations `encode_wide` and `valid_wtf8_invalid_utf8`. Is there some more direct approach I can take rather than reversing the logic of the given functions?

Since `Gen` is held abstract I don't expect to get executable code - but pseudocode or other high level instructions would be neat. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't completely clear to me whether you want to generate a string in `WTF-16 \ UTF-16` or `WTF-8 \ UTF-8`.  I think generating a WTF-16 string that isn't valid UTF-16 is probably easier, so here it goes:

You need to make sure at least one (16-bit) "character" is a surrogate that is not part of a surrogate pair.  (This example might also generate `NUL` characters in the string.)

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

pub fn gen_wtf16_invalid_utf16<R>(r: &mut R, len: usize) -> Vec<u16>
where
    R: Rng,
{
    assert!(len > 0);
    let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(len);
    for _ in 0..len {
        buf.push(r.next_u32() as u16);
    }
    // make element at position `p` a surrogate that is not part 
    // of a surrogate pair
    let p = r.gen_range(0, len-1);
    // if first elem or previous entry is not a leading surrogate
    let gen_trail = (0 == p) || (0xd800 != buf[p-1] & 0xfc00);
    // if last element or succeeding entry is not a traililng surrogate
    let gen_lead = (p == len-1) || (0xdc00 != buf[p+1] & 0xfc00);
    let (force_bits_mask, force_bits_value) = if gen_trail {
        if gen_lead {
            // trailing or leading surrogate
            (0xf800, 0xd800)
        } else {
            // trailing surrogate
            (0xfc00, 0xdc00)
        }
    } else {
        // leading surrogate
        debug_assert!(gen_lead);
        (0xfc00, 0xd800)
    };
    debug_assert_eq!(0, (force_bits_value & !force_bits_mask));
    buf[p] = (buf[p] & !force_bits_mask) | force_bits_value;
    buf
}

fn main() {
    let s = gen_wtf16_invalid_utf16(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 10);
    for c in &s {
        println!("0x{:04x}", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, `OsString` for Windows is actually backed by `Wtf8Buf` but the only way to construct that `OsString` is with `from_wide`. Some documentation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html  In particular "On Windows, strings are often arbitrary sequences of non-zero 16-bit values, interpreted as UTF-16 when it is valid to do so."  Tho it's all very confusing to me. Is the result of `OsString::from_wide(vec.as_slice()).into_string().unwrap_err()` given `vec: Vec<u16>` generated by your algorithm never a panic?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the generated sequence is not valid UTF-16 (because it contains a surrogate outside a pair); such sequence, when converted to WTF-8, cannot be valid UTF-8 (because the conversions are lossless, and converting UTF-8 back to WTF-16 would end in valid UTF-16 - but lossless means it has to be same as the original invalid UTF-16).

Comment: Right, thanks for clearing that up. Tested it and it seems to work great. Cheers!